# Why ubuntu software updaes are significantly larger than windows and android?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, downloads, bandwidth

i have recognized that updating a software in ubuntu needs much more data trasnsfer than windows and android.
for example, today i update firefox 88 to firefox 88.0.1. in ubuntu, it downloaded about 55 MB of data, in windows 10 updating firefox 88 to firefox 88.0.1 took about 15 MB or less of data download.
Or, updating chrome from 90.x.x.1 to 90.x.x.2 in ubuntu will download about 88 MB data, whereas in windows 10 it is about 10 MB or less.
also in android it is more similar to windows and it needs much less data to update softwares compared to ubuntu.

So, whay does this difference exist? is there any logic behind that? if not, is there any plan to make software updates better?

Comment: you mean microsoft and google are behind ubuntu?

Comment: No: Each is different. Each has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I haven't used windows in a decade. My last Win7 took hours to update.. (including several reboots). Did they catch up?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that on some platforms, notoriously large software is updated incrementally. It makes sense: Internet browsers are huge, they update frequently, but the binary difference may not be that big.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/UpdateGeneration

The advantage of this is saved bandwidth, but the cost is generating the binary diff between versions on the server side. And if a user skipped one or more updates, either each of the diffs from one older version to the next must still be kept on the server, or that user will get the full package anyway, in which case there is no advantage over simply always copying the big full package. So the server needs to keep at least two versions of each package available: The latest diff and the full package. In practice, it will probably be even more.

Linux package managers work differently: Not only do they generally always transfer the whole new package, not just the diff. They also allow for scripts to be executed during the process:

- a pre-install script before the package is installed
- a post-install script after the package is installed
- a pre-uninstall script before the package is uninstalled (removed)
- a post-uninstall script after the package is uninstalled

This can be used for example to convert existing databases from an older format to a newer one or to collect information from the running system (e.g. hardware information) and store it in that package's configuration database; or to safely remove any of those when a package is finally uninstalled.

Upgrading to a newer package version means uninstalling the old version and installing the new version; so in that case, all four of those scripts (if the package defines them) are executed.

But in the case of incremental upgrades, that is getting more complicated: There is no more clean uninstalling of the old package so that all the old files are removed; they have to be kept so the incoming binary diff can be applied. So any of those scripts can no longer rely on any of those files being there or not being there; they have to cope with a lot more scenarios.

It gets worse with the current trend of packing everything into snaps or flatpaks: In that case, you don't only get the new package, but everything around it; basically the better part of the underlying operating system, at least all the used libraries (direct and indirect dependencies).

I don't know if those all-inclusive package formats can handle incremental upgrades; if not, it would probably be worthwhile to think about that.